# The ConnectionSettingsTask for WP7 is not getting resolved by the compiler

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am coding for WP7 Mango ( Windows Phone 7.1 profile). The compiler is not able to resolve the ConnectionSettingsTask class.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.connectionsettingstask%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) it is in

Namespace:  Microsoft.Phone.Tasks
Assembly:  Microsoft.Phone (in Microsoft.Phone.dll)

I am not able to see this class using ObjectBrowser either.

Any help on this is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that you are targeting Windows Phone 7.1? I just tried this without any problems in an app.

Comment: @DerekLakin Yes, I am targetting to Windows Phone 7.1. VS 2010 WP7 app template added Microsoft.Phone.dll has the following properties. Path: <Program Files>\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone71\Microsoft.Phone.dll
Runtime Version: v2.0.50727
Version: 7.0.0.0.  Could you verify yours and let me know.

Comment: OK. I think, I have got it. I was using Windows Phone SDK 7.1 (Beta2). Now installing, Windows Phone SDK 7.1 (RC). Will try with that.

Answer (score 1):

The ConnectionSettingsTask class is available in Microsoft.Phone.dll of Windows Phone SDK 7.1 (RC) and NOT available in Windows Phone SDK 7.1 (Beta2).